# Cross platform flutter - how to handle dependencies?

Tags: flutter

Working on a flutter application for mobile and PC, the mobile plugins typically cover both iOS and android so the code base remains the same for mobile. Now with PC and web, the plugins are not available for all platforms.
In dart.io there are Platform.isIOS, etc. that can change behavior by platform but only at run time.
I need to conditionally import a plugin at compile time if the plugin doesn't exist on windows for example. Like camera, sqlite database, file cache, etc.
Some say to make platform dependent code go in a widget, etc. but I still need to import the widget.dart and *it* will have an import of a plugin that doesn't exist. So there are compile errors, and the only way to fix that is different versions of the code. In my case this will be most of the dart files that change.
Is there an approach to keep my code shared but with different plugins on some platforms?

Comment: Importing the Dart code for a plugin that doesn't have native implementations for some platforms is not a compile error, so the premise of the question is incorrect. Consider posting a new question with the details of a compile error you are having, since this should not be the cause

Answer (score -1):

You can check if the application is running on web by checking
if(kIsWeb) {
...
}

And then use alternative packages that work on flutter web.
For dart:io there an an alternative, which works on all platforms called universal_io

https://pub.dev/packages/universal_io

Comment: A missing package is a compile error, checking if(kIsWeb) only works at runtime after a successful compile. This is the same as the Platform.isWEB, not a solution.

Comment: The Dart code for a plugin that's in your pubspec shouldn't be a missing package.